# Oracle JDBC ignoring SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED in CONCUR_UPDATABLE ResultSet

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, foreign-keys

I have previously executed `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` within my Oracle transaction, but as soon as I call `insertRow` on the `ResultSet` obtained from a `PreparedStatement` configured as `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, I still get a `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` (`ORA-02291`: integrity constraint violated).

This is a table with "self" foreign key constraints (it represents a graph; specifically, a tree), so the constraint should in fact be satisfied when I later insert a later row.

Why is `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` apparently being ignored, and what can I do about it?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy That makes no sense. You mean the inserted row's FK. But that's the check that the SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED statement is supposed to disable.

Comment: are your constraints created as `DEFERRABLE` ? You can check it using this sql `SELECT constraint_name, table_name, DEFERRABLE 
  FROM all_constraints 
 WHERE owner = 'myschema'
   AND table_name = 'THE_TABLE';`

Comment: if not, then `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` is not going to have any effect

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes, that was the problem. Please add it as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints are not `DEFERRABLE`. You can check it using:

```
SELECT constraint_name, table_name, DEFERRABLE 
FROM all_constraints 
WHERE owner = 'myschema' 
  AND table_name = 'THE_TABLE';
```

If the constraints are not created as `DEFERRED` then `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` is not going to have any effect.

Solution: Recreate constraints as `DEFERRED`

Comment: Should it rather be created as `DEFERRABLE` ?